# How to disable links in Swift

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have built a simple messaging app using jsqmessagesviewcontroller and I was wondering if there would be any way to disable a user from sharing a website url? Thanks

Comment: When it comes to machine filtering of human languages, I can only refer you to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcZdwX4noCE or `youtube dot com slash watch?v=CcZdwX4noCE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try using 'UIDataDetectorTypes'. Here are the data types it can detect:

```
struct UIDataDetectorTypes : OptionSetType {
init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
static var PhoneNumber: UIDataDetectorTypes { get }
static var Link: UIDataDetectorTypes { get }
static var Address: UIDataDetectorTypes { get }
static var CalendarEvent: UIDataDetectorTypes { get }
static var None: UIDataDetectorTypes { get }
static var All: UIDataDetectorTypes { get }
```

}